# Sending a string like JSON from C# to javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, string, object

I have some code in `JavaScript` like this:

```
slider.setPhotos([
    { "src": "image1", "name": "n1" },
    { "src": "image2", "name": "n2" },
    { "src": "image3", "name": "n3" }
    ]);
```

And I want to set the values of `src` and `name` from `C#`.

Assume values are like this in `C#`:

```
var images = new string[] {"/images/a1.jpg", "/images/a2.jpg", "/images/a3.jpg"};

var names = new string[] {"First", "Second", "Third"};
```

How can I set these values into `JavaScript` code (i.e. in Page Load method in C# code)?

Comment: How about simply using ajax to fetch this for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the server you need to serialize the data as JSON and then you can write it into the response as HTML using something like a hidden input field.

For example you might use the [NewtonSoft](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) JSON library to serialize the JSON (which is built into [ASP MVC 4](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ASP.NET%20MVC%204%20RoadMap) however is easy to install using Nuget)

```
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(images);
```

Then render the json into the HTML (there are number of methods to do this)
e.g.

```
Response.Write(string.Concat("<input id='data' type='hidden' value='", json, "' />");
```

or

```
HiddenField jsonField = new HiddenField
{
    ID = "data"
};
jsonField.Value = json;
this.Controls.Add(jsonField);
```

or even write directly as script skipping the need to parse on the client (I still tend to use the HTML method to avoid any issues with Postbacks/Update Panels causing the script to be executed multiple times)

```
Response.Write(string.Concat("<script type='text/javascript'> var images = ", json, ";</script>");
```

On the client you can then read this JSON from the HTML and parse it. In modern browsers this is built in, or you can polyfill with something like [JSON2](https://www.google.com.au/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=10&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=json2)

e.g.

```
var field = document.getElenentById('data');
var images = JSON.parse(field.value);
```

You then have access to the data as a Javascript object.

Comment: You could even generate a script tag defining the data and not have to worry about getting the element or parsing it.

Comment: @Rawling, that's true, I've that method to my answer.

Comment: Tnx @ChrisHerring. Excellent answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `images` and `names` are of same length
You can use this

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

var images = new string[] {"/images/a1.jpg", "/images/a2.jpg", "/images/a3.jpg"};
var names = new string[] {"First", "Second", "Third"};

str.AppendLine("slider.setPhotos([");
for(int i=0; i< images.Length; i++)
{
   str.AppendLine("{ \"src\": "+ images[i] +", \"name\": "+ names[i] +" }");
   str.AppendLine( (i==images.Length-1 ? "]);":","));
}

Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
               this.GetType(), "Key007", str.ToString(), true);
```

This code will insert a script block when your page will be loaded and after that you can use that script block anywhere in your client side code.