# Unable to read JSON data from HTML input element ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, json

I know this types of questions are in abundance but a little help would be nice.

So, I have a JSON as following-

```
    <input id='JSONdata' type='hidden' value='[
  {
    "lat": 40.741895,
    "lng": -73.989308,
    "description": "<div class=\"map-popup\"><figure><img src=\"/images/default-source/default-album/img-000119d0a79213e34d3a8fba81594be76eb9.tmb-devthumb.jpg?sfvrsn=9998b2ca_1\"><figcaption><h4>\"Bowland house 3\"</h4><h5>\"\"</h5><a href=\"\" class=\"btn btn-success\">Find out more</a></figcaption></figure>/div>",
    "icon": "/sf_images/ico-0005.svg"
  },
  {
    "lat": 40.741895,
    "lng": -73.989308,
    "description": "<div class=\"map-popup\"><figure><img src=\"/images/default-source/default-album/img-000119d0a79213e34d3a8fba81594be76eb9.tmb-devthumb.jpg?sfvrsn=9998b2ca_1\"><figcaption><h4>\"Bowland house\"</h4><h5>\"\"</h5><a href=\"\" class=\"btn btn-success\">Find out more</a></figcaption></figure>/div>",
    "icon": "/sf_images/ico-0005.svg"
  }
]' />
```

This is generated from asp.net and written on the page using-

`Response.Write(string.Concat("<input id='JSONdata' type='hidden' value='", json, "' />"));`

Following the answer written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625917/sending-a-string-like-json-from-c-sharp-to-javascript). I tried to read the value by doing

```
var jq = $.noConflict();
var json2 = jq('#JSONdata');
var JSONData = JSON.parse(json2.value);
```

But I get the following error-

[image]

And unable to read the value, left me with my head scratching....

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you escape all the double quotes by replacing " with &quot; within your html?

Comment: Well it's coming from asp.net code can't really build it that way as double quote and single are two different things apparently. Just learned!

Comment: What does this have to do with C# or asp.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your line

```
var JSONData = JSON.parse(json2.value);
```

with

```
var JSONData = JSON.parse(json2[0].value);
```

Comment: Thanks Krypton.... that returns correct json now :). On the side note, if i were to change part of double quotes in the json, how would i go about and do it? like  i want the div's inside the json to be wrapped in single quote. `"<div class=\"map-popup\"></div>"` To `'<div class=\"map-popup\"></div>'`

Answer (score 0):

It means your variable `json2.value` is undefined. You're passing `undefined` into JSON.parse, and since the first letter is `u`, it says 'Unexpected token u'.

Comment: On debug console I can actually see that var json2 has value so why is json2.value undefined?

Comment: What happens when you just `console.log(json2.value)`?

Comment: I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: json2 is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13`